# Coredns Domain name policy for egress call

Tags: kubernetes, dns, acl, coredns

Can I use [coredns Domain name policy](https://github.com/coredns/policy#domain-name-policy)
to restrict or control egress call.
 For example I want to allow `google.com` and block `gitHub.com`. What implementation steps required to do this if I had kubernetes setup ready and default `coredns` pod running in it.

Comment: Take a look at [Customizing DNS Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/). Most of the customizations can be done with `ConfigMaps`.

Comment: @mario: customizing dns service not solving my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this recently using [egress-operator](https://github.com/monzo/egress-operator). You have to configure this with coredns image that you will build (follow the Readme) and it will route your egress traffic through the operator.

On the operator [external service](https://github.com/monzo/egress-operator#usage) you can whitelist the domains.

**Note:** Try to use docker local registry first instead of cloud to avoid push-pull delay